# Guided Integration Question

Tags: integration, derivatives

Part 1 is easy, but struggling to see how it helps with Part 2.

Part 1

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $y=xe^{-x}$.

Part 2

Hence show that $\int xe^{-x}dx=-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}+c$ .

Comment: What did you get as your answer to pt1? How did you get that answer? How does that answer compare to what you wish to show in 2?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that one way to show that $$\int xe^{-x}dx=-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}+c$$ is to show that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}+c\right) = xe^{-x}.$$  The first step in doing that is knowing how to differentiate $xe^{-x}$, which you presumably already did in Part 1.

Comment: thankyou, I think that is a pretty poor "guided" question

Answer (score 2):

$y' = e^{-x} - xe^{-x}$

That is part I.
How can we use that information to to find $xe^{-x}$

Integrate both sides.  Let's isolate $xe^{-x}$ on one side of the equation before integrating.

$xe^{-x} = e^{-x} -  y'\\
\int xe^{-x}\ dx = \int e^{-x} \ dx - \int y' \ dx\\
\int xe^{-x}\ dx = -e^{-x} - y+C\\
\int xe^{-x}\ dx = -e^{-x} - xe^{-x}+C$